# What does this python exception mean

Tags: python, httpurlconnection

I see the following exception sometimes when I try to hit my home page.

```
ERROR:root:HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=8003): Max retries exceeded with url:  
/snapshot/?app=cdnstats&key=28736ba5fbe151d5ff6678015c8f6ade (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>:  
[Errno 61] Connection refused)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/rokumar/CDNStats/cdnstats/app/core/views.py", line 257, in get_snapshot_data
data = templates.render_snapshot(controllers.get_snapshot_data())
File "/Users/rokumar/CDNStats/cdnstats/util.py", line 260, in decorated
expiry, mem_args, func, args, kwargs)
File "/Users/rokumar/CDNStats/cdnstats/util.py", line 227, in get_data_from_meminstance
data = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rokumar/CDNStats/cdnstats/app/core/controllers.py", line 255, in get_snapshot_data
return util.call_get_api(config.CDNSTATS_API_URL + 'snapshot/?', data)
File "/Users/rokumar/CDNStats/cdnstats/util.py", line 123, in call_get_api
raise ex
```

The following is the piece of code generating the exception.

```
def call_get_api(url, data):
try:
    data = data.copy()
    data['key'] = request.args.get('key')
    data['app'] = config.APPNAME

    query = soft_urlencode(data)
    response = requests.get(url + query)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        apiexception = APIException(response.content)
        apiexception.status_code = response.status_code
        raise apiexception
except UnicodeEncodeError as ex:
    print ex
    raise ex

except Exception as ex:
    raise ex
```

I see the exception intermittently and my app slows down heavily. I don;t really understand the exception or what is wrong. The exception says max retries exceeded but I do not have any retry logic going on.

Comment: From the part of the error saying "[Errno 61] Connection refused", I'm guessing that something is repeatedly trying and failing to make a network request. It's hard to tell anything else, since your `except Exception as ex: raise ex` code seems to be hiding the rest of the stack trace. Try deleting those last two lines, and you might get a more descriptive trace.

Answer (score 0):

in urlopen, try setting `retries=False` or `retries=1`. The default is 3 so that will probably be your retry logic going on there.

Comment: This does not seem to help me in any way. The retry=3 even if there should seem to hurt the application in any way,